# Unable to rename VPN connection because Save button is gray

Tags: networking, vpn, certificates

I was wishing to rename my VPN connection, but was unable, because `Save` button is gray.

[image]

When running from command line it says:

```
$ nm-connection-editor
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
** Message: Cannot save connection due to error: Editor initializing...
** Message: Cannot save connection due to error: Invalid setting VPN: cert-pass
```

How to overcome?

Comment: It's looking for a password... maybe the "Private Key Password", or one of your .pem files is incorrect.

Comment: I can connect, so whatever password exists, it is correct

Comment: To see if it's the problem, type ANYTHING (at least 8 characters) into th "Private Key Password" field and see if the SAVE button becomes enabled.

Comment: You can probably rename it in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`...`sudo mv VPN1 new_name`

Comment: To see if it's a permission problem, type `sudo nm-connection-editor` and see if the SAVE button is now available.

Comment: @heynnema entering anything into key field enables save button; `sudo` doesn't help

Comment: @heynnema copying of a file `VPN1` to `VPN2` didn't lead to appearence of a new connection. I am afraid to loose connection if rename.

Comment: Then open the connection profile in your favorite editor and change the "id=" line to the new name. Let me know how that works for you, so I can write a formal answer for you.